# Sources for HP's A Graphics Language?

Tags: hp

I'm poking about in the usual places, but not having any luck, does anyone have any good introductory information for HP's AGL, "A Graphics Language"?

Comment: Do you mean "HP-GL" instead of "AGL"?

Comment: No, AGL was an extension to BASIC and FORTRAN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-GL#AGL) was an extension to BASIC and FORTRAN, which was implemented on [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_9800_series#Programming) [HP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_2640#Models) [systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_2100#Operating_systems). It was used to describe what you wanted drawn, and the BASIC/FORTRAN system would generate HP-GL to drive a plotter.

The most accessible manuals seem to be [here](http://www.series80.org/Manuals/). The [HP-86/87 Plotter ROM Manual](http://www.series80.org/PDFs/HP86-Plotter.pdf), describes the changes to the HP-86 BASIC when using a plotter. These don't seem to be very extensive, suggesting that you also need to look at an HP-86 BASIC manual to learn how the graphics commands worked. However, that manual doesn't seem to be on that site, although the HP-85 manual is.

Comment: This is one of the few manuals I've seen that mentions the plotter [Digitizing Sight](http://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=888): a precision optical sight that replaces a pen which allows quite accurate (manual) digitization of drawings that fit in the plotter. The reading commands are built in to the Plotter/AGL extension